# Pivot by group for unequal data size

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo, reshape2

I have the following DF:

```
DF = structure(list(ID = c(21785L, 21785L, 21785L), V1 = c(0.828273303, 
                                                  6.404590021, 0.775568448), V2 = c(2L, 3L, 2L), V3 = c(NA, 1.122899914, 
                                                                                                        0.850113234), V4 = c(NA, 4L, 3L), V5 = c(NA, 0.866757168, 0.868943246
                                                                                                        ), V6 = c(NA, 5L, 4L), V7 = c(NA, 0.563804788, 0.728656328), 
           V8 = c(NA, 6L, 5L), V9 = c(NA, 0.888109208, 0.823803733), 
           V10 = c(NA, 7L, 6L), V11 = c(NA, 0.578834113, 0.863467391
           ), V12 = c(NA, 1L, 7L), V13 = c(NA, NA, 0.939920869)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(5L, 
                                                                                                      163L, 167L))

Output: 
Row      ID        V1 V2        V3 V4        V5 V6        V7 V8        V9 V10       V11 V12       V13
5   21785 0.8282733  2        NA NA        NA NA        NA NA        NA  NA        NA  NA        NA
163 21785 6.4045900  3 1.1228999  4 0.8667572  5 0.5638048  6 0.8881092   7 0.5788341   1        NA
167 21785 0.7755684  2 0.8501132  3 0.8689432  4 0.7286563  5 0.8238037   6 0.8634674   7 0.9399209
```

The data can be broken down into 3 parts:

1. ID per participant
2. Odd Columns representing standardized heart rate
3. Even columns representing day number of week (1 = sunday)

I have 100 plus unique participants and 3000 rows of data with unequal data per day, hence the NAs.

**I would like to pivot the data into one column per part**

- so that: col1 = ID, col2 = HR, col3 = Weekday

I have tried several methods based on similar questions such as:

```
    # melt the data frame to put all the metrics in a single column
    DF2 = reshape2::melt(DF, id.vars = c("ID"))

    # split the data by ID
    DF3 = split(DF2, DF2$ID)

    # allocate empty DF with 3 columns for future appending
    DF_Organized = data.frame()[1,3]

    # make the data into 3 new columns, 1 for ID, HR, weekday
    for (m in 1:length(DF3)){

    DF_tmp = DF3[m] %>%
      data.frame %>% na.omit() # convert to DF, remove NAs
      setNames(., c("ID","colx","Value")) %>% # set names for clarity
      mutate(ind = rep(c(1, 2),length.out = n())) %>% # assign 1 to amplitude and 2 to day values in each row
      group_by(ind) %>% # group by value type
      mutate(id = row_number()) %>% # make new column that determines location of data by previous assignment
      spread(ind, Value) %>% # organize data by new ID
      select(-id) #clean 

    # reorganize the NAs to the bottom
DF_tmp2 = setNames(do.call(function(...) rowr::cbind.fill(..., fill = NA),
                          lapply(DF_tmp, na.omit)),colnames(DF_tmp)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  select(-colx) %>% 
  setNames(., c("ID","HR","Weekday")) # set names for clarity
```

I get close but not accurate:

*Actual Output:*

```
> DF_tmp2
      ID HR        Weekday
1  21785 0.8282733 6.4045900
2  21785 0.7755684 2.0000000
3  21785 3.0000000 2.0000000
4  21785 1.1228999 0.8501132
```

.
.
.
There's misalignment and inaccurate combinations. Any help is appreciated.

**Expected Output:**

```
   > DF_tmp2
          ID HR        Weekday
    1  21785 0.8282733 2.0000000
    2  21785 6.4045900 3.0000000
    3  21785 1.1228999 4.0000000
    4  21785 0.8667572 5.0000000
    5  21875 0.5638048 6.0000000
.
.
.
```

Comment: What does the last column represent? It doesn't seem to have a matching weekday column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) pivot_longer** Define the `v.names` column names and the number of pairs `k`.  Then add `V14` since `V13` seems unmatched and then change the names to something which identifies the columns, i.e. ID, HR 1, Weekday 1, HR 2, Weekday 2, etc.  With these names we can employ `pivot_longer`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

v.names <- c("HR", "Weekday")
k <- ncol(DF) %/% 2L  # 7L = no. of (HR, Weekday) pairs

DF %>% 
  mutate(V14 = V12 %% 7L + 1L, n = 1:n()) %>%
  set_names("ID", cross2(v.names, 1:k) %>% map(lift(paste)), "n") %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, n), names_to = c(".value", "Num"), names_sep = " ") %>%
  drop_na %>%
  arrange(n, Num) %>%
  select(-n, -Num)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
      ID    HR Weekday
   <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 21785 0.828       2
 2 21785 6.40        3
 3 21785 1.12        4
 4 21785 0.867       5
 5 21785 0.564       6
 6 21785 0.888       7
 7 21785 0.579       1
 8 21785 0.776       2
 9 21785 0.850       3
10 21785 0.869       4
11 21785 0.729       5
12 21785 0.824       6
13 21785 0.863       7
14 21785 0.940       1
```

**2) Base R** We can alternately use `reshape` in base R in much the same way.  `v.names` and `k` are from above.  Note that `reshape` automatically adds an `id` column giving the row number in the original data frame so we do not have to add it ourself as we did in (1).

```
DF2 <- transform(DF, V14 = V12 %% 7L + 1L)
names(DF2)[-1] <- outer(v.names, 1:k, paste)

long <- na.omit(reshape(DF2, dir = "long",
  varying = lapply(v.names, grep, names(DF2)), v.names = v.names))
long[order(long$id, long$time), c("ID", "HR", "Weekday")]
```

**3) data.table**

Using DF2 from (2)

```
library(data.table)

DT2 <- data.table(DF2)[, row := .I]
DT2 <- na.omit(melt(DT2, idvars = c("ID", "row"), 
  measure.vars = sapply(v.names, grep, names(DT2), simplify = FALSE)))

setkey(DT2, row, Weekday)
DT2[, c("ID", "HR", "Weekday")]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, though I keep getting "Pivot_longer" not found/not part of tidyr/tidyverse. I also get `Error in rval[, idvar] <- ids : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix` with the full data set using the base-R you supplied, not sure why. The answer below works though.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of tidyr.  pivot_longer was only recently added to that package .  Also I have updated this answer a number of times so be sure you are using the latest update.

Answer (score 3):

```
DF %>%
  gather(col, val, -ID) %>%
  mutate(col = if_else(str_ends(col, "0|2|4|6|8"), "Weekday", "HR")) %>%
  group_by(col) %>%
  mutate(instance = row_number()) %>%
  spread(col, val) %>%
  filter(!is.na(HR))


## A tibble: 14 x 4
#      ID instance    HR Weekday
#   <int>    <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 21785        1 0.828       2
# 2 21785        2 6.40        3
# 3 21785        3 0.776       2
# 4 21785        5 1.12        4
# 5 21785        6 0.850       3
# 6 21785        8 0.867       5
# 7 21785        9 0.869       4
# 8 21785       11 0.564       6
# 9 21785       12 0.729       5
#10 21785       14 0.888       7
#11 21785       15 0.824       6
#12 21785       17 0.579       1
#13 21785       18 0.863       7
#14 21785       21 0.940      NA
```

Comment: I think G. Grothendieck's answer is more complete. It relies on the most current version of tidyr (1.0.0), which introduces `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` as more powerful (and hopefully intuitive) alternatives to `gather` and `spread`. You may need to upgrade your `tidyr` and/or `tidyverse` libraries to get those.

Comment: @Jon Spring, We can readily add `V14` and use `pivot_*` like this: `library(dplyr); library(stringr); library(tidyr); DF %>%
  mutate(V14 = V12 %% 7L + 1L) %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  mutate(name = if_else(str_ends(name, "0|2|4|6|8"), "Weekday", "HR")) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(instance = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider %>%
  drop_na %>% arrange(instance) %>% select(-instance)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (m in 1:length(DF3)){
  
  DF_tmp = DF3[m] %>%
    data.frame %>% 
    na.omit() %>% 
    setNames(., c("ID","colx","Value")) %>% # set names for clarity
    
    mutate(ind = substring(colx, 2) %>% as.numeric() %% 2) %>% # assign 1 to amplitude and 2 to day values in each row
    group_by(ind) %>% # group by value type
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>% # make new column that determines location of data by previous assignment
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-colx) %>% 
    spread(ind, Value)
  # reorganize the NAs to the bottom
  DF_tmp2 = setNames(do.call(function(...) rowr::cbind.fill(..., fill = NA),
                             lapply(DF_tmp, na.omit)),colnames(DF_tmp)) %>% 
    na.omit() %>% 
    select(-id) %>% 
    setNames(., c("ID","Weekday","HR")) %>% # set names for clarity
    arrange(Weekday)
}
```